# Sort QTableView QDateTime Column instead of string sort

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

In my QtableView there are four column. The 0th col is for **date in dd-MM-yyyy** format. and the other three column contains string so for them sorting is not a problem (can be done using `QSortFilterProxyModel` class) but for col 0 i want sorting from right to left ( for both ascending and descending order).

Comment: I do not understand what you say in the following sentence: **but for col 0 i want sorting from right to left**, also must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: May be he is asking to sort date as string

Comment: yes sure. for col 0 data are in dd-MM-yyyy format that means say my datas are (20-07-2017,12-09-2017) so when i arrange them in ascending order i get the result (12-09-2017,20-07-2017) instead of (20-07-2017,12-09-2017). in my understanding this is happening coz in col 0 strings are arranged from left to right order and if we can arrange it from right to left order then we will get the correct result.

Comment: As I get you want to sort a QDateTime field instead of sorting text string for col 0. am I right?

Comment: @saeed you are right. that is a QDate field in dd-MM-yyyy format

Comment: @Rintu. You don't really want right to left order. That would give you, e.g. (`8002-40-01, 7102-11-01, 7102-90-01`). It is best to avoid sorting by string representation, and sort by the original value instead (i.e. as an `int`, `float`, `QDate`, etc).

Comment: @ekhumoro i don't know how to implement this.

Comment: @Rintu. You already have an answer that (almost) shows you how to do it. The conversion for column zero should be like this: `dataleft = QtCore.QDate.fromString(dataleft, 'dd-MM-yyyy')`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example of **customSortingModel**

```
self.tableView = QtGui.TableView(self)
self.table_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 0)
self.proxyModel = CustomSortingModel(self)

self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.table_model)
self.tableView.setModel(self.proxyModel)

class CustomSortingModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def lessThan(self,left,right):

        col = left.column()

        dataleft = left.data()
        dataright = right.data()

        if col == 2:
            dataleft = float(dataleft)
            dataright = float(dataright)
        elif col == 3:
            dataleft = QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(dataleft, "d/M/yy").addYears(100)
            dataright = QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(dataright, "d/M/yy").addYears(100)

        return dataleft < dataright
```

Comment: what is the addYears(100)?

Comment: .addYears(100) is extra for make sure **QDateTime** type

Comment: @saeed. That is silly - it cannot return anything other than a `QDate`.